No map received. Timed out waiting for transform from base_footprint to map
General
I am struggling with setting up a nav2 stack which should run with a static map (predefined map). (Note that i am currently using the map for the gazebo world which i am currently using as a temporary test). I only intend to use DWB since the target environment is an open square with only dynamic obstacles. My functions will thus only use NavigateToPose.
Specifications
My specs:

ROS2 Humble
Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Gazebo 11.10

Problem formulation
Now my problem, I've created launch files, param files, behavior tree files for my situation, mainly copying the pre existing nav2 files.
My files can be found on GitHub:
https://github.com/DVA490-474-Project-Course/robot-controller-interface/tree/main/config
However when i try it out by first starting gazebo as a temporary test:
ros2 launch turtlebot3_gazebo turtlebot3_world.launch.py

And then launch my launch files
ros2 launch /path/to/config/launch/navigation_launch_ssl_robocup.py

Then i get the following issues:
[planner_server-3] [INFO] [1729844723.366379990] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_footprint to map to become available, tf error: Invalid frame ID "map" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist

[controller_server-2] [WARN] [1729844723.498594870] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Can't update static costmap layer, no map received

What I've tried
I've done:
ros2 topic echo /map

which shows the map is published.
I've tried creating a static_transform_publisher but it caused other problems then:
[lifecycle_manager-8] [INFO] [1729930720.912561342] [lifecycle_manager_navigation]: Waiting for service static_transform_publisher/get_state...

I've analyzed the entire configuration guide (https://docs.nav2.org/configuration/index.html) for nav2 to try and find anything i might have missed and I've tried the parameters I feel could make a difference.
I do set initial pose in AMCL. But still doesn't solve problem.
I've seen people talk about this being caused by AMCL not finding the map, but mine does:
[amcl-6] [INFO] [1729844715.364223648] [amcl]: Received a 384 X 384 map @ 0.050 m/pix

What does work
When i go with the base SLAM and nav2 stack then it works fine and my software does navigation as intended. but my platform wont have the processing to do SLAM, i must do the most lightweight navigation so I must use a predefined map. how i run when it works:
ros2 launch turtlebot3_gazebo turtlebot3_world.launch.py

ros2 launch slam_toolbox online_async_launch.py

ros2 launch nav2_bringup navigation_launch.py

Here i run my software which does NavigateToPose

Appendix
(Note that this is from start until i close with Ctrl+ctT)
nav2:
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/carl/.ros/log/2024-10-25-10-25-10-985205-carl-ThinkPad-T14-Gen-1-5889
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [map_server-1]: process started with pid [5904]
[INFO] [controller_server-2]: process started with pid [5906]
[INFO] [planner_server-3]: process started with pid [5908]
[INFO] [behavior_server-4]: process started with pid [5910]
[INFO] [bt_navigator-5]: process started with pid [5912]
[INFO] [amcl-6]: process started with pid [5914]
[INFO] [lifecycle_manager-7]: process started with pid [5916]
[controller_server-2] [INFO] [1729844712.458198668] [controller_server]: 
[controller_server-2]   controller_server lifecycle node launched. 
[controller_server-2]   Waiting on external lifecycle transitions to activate
[controller_server-2]   See https://design.ros2.org/articles/node_lifecycle.html for more information.
[controller_server-2] [INFO] [1729844712.476306818] [controller_server]: Creating controller server
[behavior_server-4] [INFO] [1729844712.491544930] [behavior_server]: 
[behavior_server-4]     behavior_server lifecycle node launched. 
[behavior_server-4]     Waiting on external lifecycle transitions to activate
[behavior_server-4]     See https://design.ros2.org/articles/node_lifecycle.html for more information.
[controller_server-2] [INFO] [1729844712.555201712] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: 
[controller_server-2]   local_costmap lifecycle node launched. 
[controller_server-2]   Waiting on external lifecycle transitions to activate
[controller_server-2]   See https://design.ros2.org/articles/node_lifecycle.html for more information.
[controller_server-2] [INFO] [1729844712.559730117] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Creating Costmap
[map_server-1] [INFO] [1729844712.793579097] [map_server]: 
[map_server-1]  map_server lifecycle node launched. 
[map_server-1]  Waiting on external lifecycle transitions to activate
[map_server-1]  See https://design.ros2.org/articles/node_lifecycle.html for more information.
[map_server-1] [INFO] [1729844712.794428813] [map_server]: Creating
[bt_navigator-5] [INFO] [1729844712.824780148] [bt_navigator]: 
[bt_navigator-5]    bt_navigator lifecycle node launched. 
[bt_navigator-5]    Waiting on external lifecycle transitions to activate
[bt_navigator-5]    See https://design.ros2.org/articles/node_lifecycle.html for more information.
[bt_navigator-5] [INFO] [1729844712.845158340] [bt_navigator]: Creating
[amcl-6] [INFO] [1729844712.983281655] [amcl]: 
[amcl-6]    amcl lifecycle node launched. 
[amcl-6]    Waiting on external lifecycle transitions to activate
[amcl-6]    See https://design.ros2.org/articles/node_lifecycle.html for more information.
[amcl-6] [INFO] [1729844712.984034421] [amcl]: Creating
[planner_server-3] [INFO] [1729844713.000641542] [planner_server]: 
[planner_server-3]  planner_server lifecycle node launched. 
[planner_server-3]  Waiting on external lifecycle transitions to activate
[planner_server-3]  See https://design.ros2.org/articles/node_lifecycle.html for more information.
[planner_server-3] [INFO] [1729844713.011233087] [planner_server]: Creating
[lifecycle_manager-7] [INFO] [1729844713.102088402] [lifecycle_manager_navigation]: Creating
[lifecycle_manager-7] [INFO] [1729844713.176322480] [lifecycle_manager_navigation]: Creating and initializing lifecycle service clients
[planner_server-3] [INFO] [1729844713.217656543] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: 
[planner_server-3]  global_costmap lifecycle node launched. 
[planner_server-3]  Waiting on external lifecycle transitions to activate
[planner_server-3]  See https://design.ros2.org/articles/node_lifecycle.html for more information.
[planner_server-3] [INFO] [1729844713.222362734] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Creating Costmap
[lifecycle_manager-7] [INFO] [1729844713.791148682] [lifecycle_manager_navigation]: Starting managed nodes bringup...
[lifecycle_manager-7] [INFO] [1729844713.791192662] [lifecycle_manager_navigation]: Configuring map_server
[map_server-1] [INFO] [1729844713.791535539] [map_server]: Configuring
[map_server-1] [INFO] [map_io]: Loading yaml file: /home/carl/dev/dva490/robot-controller-interface/config/map/ssl_robocup_map.yaml
[map_server-1] [DEBUG] [map_io]: resolution: 0.05
[map_server-1] [DEBUG] [map_io]: origin[0]: 0
[map_server-1] [DEBUG] [map_io]: origin[1]: 0
[map_server-1] [DEBUG] [map_io]: origin[2]: 0
[map_server-1] [DEBUG] [map_io]: free_thresh: 0.196
[map_server-1] [DEBUG] [map_io]: occupied_thresh: 0.65
[map_server-1] [DEBUG] [map_io]: mode: trinary
[map_server-1] [DEBUG] [map_io]: negate: 0
[map_server-1] [INFO] [map_io]: Loading image_file: /home/carl/dev/dva490/robot-controller-interface/config/map/temp_map.pgm
[map_server-1] [DEBUG] [map_io]: Read map /home/carl/dev/dva490/robot-controller-interface/config/map/temp_map.pgm: 384 X 384 map @ 0.05 m/cell
[lifecycle_manager-7] [INFO] [1729844713.848644801] [lifecycle_manager_navigation]: Configuring controller_server
[controller_server-2] [INFO] [1729844713.849093167] [controller_server]: Configuring controller interface
[controller_server-2] [INFO] [1729844713.849374957] [controller_server]: getting goal checker plugins..
[controller_server-2] [INFO] [1729844713.851170875] [controller_server]: Controller frequency set to 20.0000Hz
[controller_server-2] [INFO] [1729844713.851803936] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Configuring
[controller_server-2] [INFO] [1729844713.889130857] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Using plugin "static_layer"
[controller_server-2] [INFO] [1729844713.912631603] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Subscribing to the map topic (map) with transient local durability
[controller_server-2] [INFO] [1729844713.925153983] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Subscribing to updates
[controller_server-2] [INFO] [1729844713.932286238] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Initialized plugin "static_layer"
[controller_server-2] [INFO] [1729844713.932386309] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Using plugin "inflation_layer"
[controller_server-2] [INFO] [1729844713.942473047] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Initialized plugin "inflation_layer"
[controller_server-2] [INFO] [1729844713.942799431] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Using plugin "obstacle_layer"
[controller_server-2] [INFO] [1729844713.950852242] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Subscribed to Topics: scan
[controller_server-2] [INFO] [1729844713.971703828] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Initialized plugin "obstacle_layer"
[controller_server-2] [INFO] [1729844714.044494450] [controller_server]: Created progress_checker : progress_checker of type nav2_controller::SimpleProgressChecker
[controller_server-2] [INFO] [1729844714.059061842] [controller_server]: Created goal checker : general_goal_checker of type nav2_controller::SimpleGoalChecker
[controller_server-2] [INFO] [1729844714.062309092] [controller_server]: Controller Server has general_goal_checker  goal checkers available.
[controller_server-2] [INFO] [1729844714.075655285] [controller_server]: Created controller : FollowPath of type dwb_core::DWBLocalPlanner
[controller_server-2] [INFO] [1729844714.077232265] [controller_server]: Setting transform_tolerance to 0.200000
[controller_server-2] [INFO] [1729844714.158670677] [controller_server]: Using critic "RotateToGoal" (dwb_critics::RotateToGoalCritic)
[controller_server-2] [INFO] [1729844714.160679167] [controller_server]: Critic plugin initialized
[controller_server-2] [INFO] [1729844714.160963820] [controller_server]: Using critic "Oscillation" (dwb_critics::OscillationCritic)
[controller_server-2] [INFO] [1729844714.161525326] [controller_server]: Critic plugin initialized
[controller_server-2] [INFO] [1729844714.161829340] [controller_server]: Using critic "BaseObstacle" (dwb_critics::BaseObstacleCritic)
[controller_server-2] [INFO] [1729844714.162275505] [controller_server]: Critic plugin initialized
[controller_server-2] [INFO] [1729844714.162574839] [controller_server]: Using critic "GoalAlign" (dwb_critics::GoalAlignCritic)
[controller_server-2] [INFO] [1729844714.163666207] [controller_server]: Critic plugin initialized
[controller_server-2] [INFO] [1729844714.164609861] [controller_server]: Using critic "PathAlign" (dwb_critics::PathAlignCritic)
[controller_server-2] [INFO] [1729844714.166082203] [controller_server]: Critic plugin initialized
[controller_server-2] [INFO] [1729844714.166304833] [controller_server]: Using critic "PathDist" (dwb_critics::PathDistCritic)
[controller_server-2] [INFO] [1729844714.166611923] [controller_server]: Critic plugin initialized
[controller_server-2] [INFO] [1729844714.166775481] [controller_server]: Using critic "GoalDist" (dwb_critics::GoalDistCritic)
[controller_server-2] [INFO] [1729844714.167065846] [controller_server]: Critic plugin initialized
[controller_server-2] [INFO] [1729844714.167103875] [controller_server]: Controller Server has FollowPath  controllers available.
[lifecycle_manager-7] [INFO] [1729844714.208542763] [lifecycle_manager_navigation]: Configuring planner_server
[planner_server-3] [INFO] [1729844714.211835851] [planner_server]: Configuring
[planner_server-3] [INFO] [1729844714.212211670] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Configuring
[planner_server-3] [INFO] [1729844714.266252265] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Using plugin "static_layer"
[planner_server-3] [INFO] [1729844714.293732035] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Subscribing to the map topic (map) with transient local durability
[planner_server-3] [INFO] [1729844714.305818209] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Subscribing to updates
[planner_server-3] [INFO] [1729844714.319328886] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Initialized plugin "static_layer"
[planner_server-3] [INFO] [1729844714.319615770] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Using plugin "inflation_layer"
[planner_server-3] [INFO] [1729844714.324323161] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Initialized plugin "inflation_layer"
[planner_server-3] [INFO] [1729844714.324413417] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Using plugin "obstacle_layer"
[planner_server-3] [INFO] [1729844714.325093920] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Subscribed to Topics: scan
[planner_server-3] [INFO] [1729844714.362956236] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Initialized plugin "obstacle_layer"
[planner_server-3] [INFO] [1729844714.437348933] [planner_server]: Created global planner plugin GridBased of type nav2_navfn_planner/NavfnPlanner
[planner_server-3] [INFO] [1729844714.437770611] [planner_server]: Configuring plugin GridBased of type NavfnPlanner
[planner_server-3] [INFO] [1729844714.443365248] [planner_server]: Planner Server has GridBased  planners available.
[lifecycle_manager-7] [INFO] [1729844714.526776809] [lifecycle_manager_navigation]: Configuring behavior_server
[behavior_server-4] [INFO] [1729844714.527567650] [behavior_server]: Configuring
[behavior_server-4] [INFO] [1729844714.593621753] [behavior_server]: Creating behavior plugin spin of type nav2_behaviors/Spin
[behavior_server-4] [INFO] [1729844714.598543870] [behavior_server]: Configuring spin
[behavior_server-4] [INFO] [1729844714.665586391] [behavior_server]: Creating behavior plugin backup of type nav2_behaviors/BackUp
[behavior_server-4] [INFO] [1729844714.669444490] [behavior_server]: Configuring backup
[behavior_server-4] [INFO] [1729844714.697528451] [behavior_server]: Creating behavior plugin drive_on_heading of type nav2_behaviors/DriveOnHeading
[behavior_server-4] [INFO] [1729844714.705142501] [behavior_server]: Configuring drive_on_heading
[behavior_server-4] [INFO] [1729844714.751203745] [behavior_server]: Creating behavior plugin wait of type nav2_behaviors/Wait
[behavior_server-4] [INFO] [1729844714.759496437] [behavior_server]: Configuring wait
[lifecycle_manager-7] [INFO] [1729844714.798963163] [lifecycle_manager_navigation]: Configuring bt_navigator
[bt_navigator-5] [INFO] [1729844714.799344225] [bt_navigator]: Configuring
[lifecycle_manager-7] [INFO] [1729844715.221842196] [lifecycle_manager_navigation]: Configuring amcl
[amcl-6] [INFO] [1729844715.222248450] [amcl]: Configuring
[amcl-6] [INFO] [1729844715.222384088] [amcl]: initTransforms
[amcl-6] [INFO] [1729844715.292039963] [amcl]: initPubSub
[amcl-6] [INFO] [1729844715.322301370] [amcl]: Subscribed to map topic.
[lifecycle_manager-7] [INFO] [1729844715.356239589] [lifecycle_manager_navigation]: Activating map_server
[map_server-1] [INFO] [1729844715.359107348] [map_server]: Activating
[map_server-1] [INFO] [1729844715.361887916] [map_server]: Creating bond (map_server) to lifecycle manager.
[amcl-6] [INFO] [1729844715.364223648] [amcl]: Received a 384 X 384 map @ 0.050 m/pix
[lifecycle_manager-7] [INFO] [1729844715.495048141] [lifecycle_manager_navigation]: Server map_server connected with bond.
[lifecycle_manager-7] [INFO] [1729844715.495247157] [lifecycle_manager_navigation]: Activating controller_server
[controller_server-2] [INFO] [1729844715.497114219] [controller_server]: Activating
[controller_server-2] [INFO] [1729844715.497424736] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Activating
[controller_server-2] [INFO] [1729844715.497540395] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Checking transform
[controller_server-2] [INFO] [1729844715.498069357] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: start
[controller_server-2] [INFO] [1729844715.749668162] [controller_server]: Creating bond (controller_server) to lifecycle manager.
[lifecycle_manager-7] [INFO] [1729844715.863186043] [lifecycle_manager_navigation]: Server controller_server connected with bond.
[lifecycle_manager-7] [INFO] [1729844715.863470287] [lifecycle_manager_navigation]: Activating planner_server
[planner_server-3] [INFO] [1729844715.865585649] [planner_server]: Activating
[planner_server-3] [INFO] [1729844715.866053886] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Activating
[planner_server-3] [INFO] [1729844715.866163519] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Checking transform
[planner_server-3] [INFO] [1729844715.866332543] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_footprint to map to become available, tf error: Invalid frame ID "map" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
[planner_server-3] [INFO] [1729844716.366400248] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_footprint to map to become available, tf error: Invalid frame ID "map" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
[planner_server-3] [INFO] [1729844716.866296399] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_footprint to map to become available, tf error: Invalid frame ID "map" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
[planner_server-3] [INFO] [1729844717.366480894] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_footprint to map to become available, tf error: Invalid frame ID "map" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
[controller_server-2] [WARN] [1729844717.498827669] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Can't update static costmap layer, no map received
[planner_server-3] [INFO] [1729844717.866387169] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_footprint to map to become available, tf error: Invalid frame ID "map" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
[planner_server-3] [INFO] [1729844718.366430433] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_footprint to map to become available, tf error: Invalid frame ID "map" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
[planner_server-3] [INFO] [1729844718.866332988] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_footprint to map to become available, tf error: Invalid frame ID "map" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
[planner_server-3] [INFO] [1729844719.366414265] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_footprint to map to become available, tf error: Invalid frame ID "map" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
[controller_server-2] [WARN] [1729844719.498889794] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Can't update static costmap layer, no map received
[planner_server-3] [INFO] [1729844719.866367648] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_footprint to map to become available, tf error: Invalid frame ID "map" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
[planner_server-3] [INFO] [1729844720.366407417] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_footprint to map to become available, tf error: Invalid frame ID "map" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
[planner_server-3] [INFO] [1729844720.866301054] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_footprint to map to become available, tf error: Invalid frame ID "map" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
[planner_server-3] [INFO] [1729844721.366438223] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_footprint to map to become available, tf error: Invalid frame ID "map" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
[controller_server-2] [WARN] [1729844721.498930923] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Can't update static costmap layer, no map received
[planner_server-3] [INFO] [1729844721.866429141] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_footprint to map to become available, tf error: Invalid frame ID "map" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
[planner_server-3] [INFO] [1729844722.366358444] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_footprint to map to become available, tf error: Invalid frame ID "map" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
[planner_server-3] [INFO] [1729844722.866346177] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_footprint to map to become available, tf error: Invalid frame ID "map" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
[planner_server-3] [INFO] [1729844723.366379990] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_footprint to map to become available, tf error: Invalid frame ID "map" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
[controller_server-2] [WARN] [1729844723.498594870] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Can't update static costmap layer, no map received
[planner_server-3] [INFO] [1729844723.866388458] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_footprint to map to become available, tf error: Invalid frame ID "map" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
[planner_server-3] [INFO] [1729844724.366338242] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_footprint to map to become available, tf error: Invalid frame ID "map" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
[planner_server-3] [INFO] [1729844724.866307257] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_footprint to map to become available, tf error: Invalid frame ID "map" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
[planner_server-3] [INFO] [1729844725.366469803] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_footprint to map to become available, tf error: Invalid frame ID "map" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
[controller_server-2] [WARN] [1729844725.498679136] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Can't update static costmap layer, no map received
[planner_server-3] [INFO] [1729844725.866475767] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_footprint to map to become available, tf error: Invalid frame ID "map" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
^C[WARNING] [launch]: user interrupted with ctrl-c (SIGINT)
[lifecycle_manager-7] [INFO] [1729844726.278652857] [rclcpp]: signal_handler(signum=2)
[bt_navigator-5] [INFO] [1729844726.278652743] [rclcpp]: signal_handler(signum=2)
[behavior_server-4] [INFO] [1729844726.278677406] [rclcpp]: signal_handler(signum=2)
[behavior_server-4] [INFO] [1729844726.279379769] [behavior_server]: Running Nav2 LifecycleNode rcl preshutdown (behavior_server)
[behavior_server-4] [INFO] [1729844726.279801379] [behavior_server]: Cleaning up
[amcl-6] [INFO] [1729844726.278697015] [rclcpp]: signal_handler(signum=2)
[amcl-6] [INFO] [1729844726.280202972] [amcl]: Running Nav2 LifecycleNode rcl preshutdown (amcl)
[amcl-6] [INFO] [1729844726.280679841] [amcl]: Cleaning up
[map_server-1] [INFO] [1729844726.278784028] [rclcpp]: signal_handler(signum=2)
[map_server-1] [INFO] [1729844726.279385902] [map_server]: Running Nav2 LifecycleNode rcl preshutdown (map_server)
[map_server-1] [INFO] [1729844726.280134270] [map_server]: Deactivating
[map_server-1] [INFO] [1729844726.280480410] [map_server]: Destroying bond (map_server) to lifecycle manager.
[controller_server-2] [INFO] [1729844726.278976680] [rclcpp]: signal_handler(signum=2)
[controller_server-2] [INFO] [1729844726.279379396] [controller_server]: Running Nav2 LifecycleNode rcl preshutdown (controller_server)
[controller_server-2] [INFO] [1729844726.279801376] [controller_server]: Deactivating
[controller_server-2] [INFO] [1729844726.280170287] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Deactivating
[planner_server-3] [INFO] [1729844726.279419865] [rclcpp]: signal_handler(signum=2)
[planner_server-3] [INFO] [1729844726.280963218] [planner_server]: Running Nav2 LifecycleNode rcl preshutdown (planner_server)
[planner_server-3] [INFO] [1729844726.281254084] [planner_server]: Destroying bond (planner_server) to lifecycle manager.
[planner_server-3] [INFO] [1729844726.284363866] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: start
[planner_server-3] [ERROR] [1729844726.284882883] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Caught exception in callback for transition 13
[planner_server-3] [ERROR] [1729844726.284908339] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Original error: could not create subscription: rcl node's context is invalid, at ./src/rcl/node.c:428
[planner_server-3] [ERROR] [1729844726.284944692] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Failed to finish transition 3. Current state is now: errorprocessing (Could not publish transition: publisher's context is invalid, at ./src/rcl/publisher.c:389, at ./src/rcl_lifecycle.c:368)
[planner_server-3] [INFO] [1729844726.284959964] [planner_server]: Activating plugin GridBased of type NavfnPlanner
[planner_server-3] [ERROR] [1729844726.285056782] [planner_server]: Caught exception in callback for transition 13
[planner_server-3] [ERROR] [1729844726.285066278] [planner_server]: Original error: could not create service: rcl node's context is invalid, at ./src/rcl/node.c:428
[planner_server-3] [ERROR] [1729844726.285084978] [planner_server]: Failed to finish transition 3. Current state is now: errorprocessing (Could not publish transition: publisher's context is invalid, at ./src/rcl/publisher.c:389, at ./src/rcl_lifecycle.c:368)
[lifecycle_manager-7] [INFO] [1729844726.283498680] [lifecycle_manager_navigation]: Running Nav2 LifecycleManager rcl preshutdown (lifecycle_manager_navigation)
[bt_navigator-5] [INFO] [1729844726.283566136] [bt_navigator]: Running Nav2 LifecycleNode rcl preshutdown (bt_navigator)
[bt_navigator-5] [INFO] [1729844726.283921608] [bt_navigator]: Cleaning up
[planner_server-3] [INFO] [1729844726.293932129] [planner_server]: Destroying plugin GridBased of type NavfnPlanner
[map_server-1] [INFO] [1729844726.302636424] [map_server]: Cleaning up
[map_server-1] [INFO] [1729844726.303509917] [map_server]: Destroying bond (map_server) to lifecycle manager.
[controller_server-2] [INFO] [1729844726.303737134] [controller_server]: Destroying bond (controller_server) to lifecycle manager.
[controller_server-2] [INFO] [1729844726.317844866] [controller_server]: Cleaning up
[controller_server-2] [INFO] [1729844726.328208601] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Cleaning up
[behavior_server-4] [INFO] [1729844726.304214376] [behavior_server]: Destroying bond (behavior_server) to lifecycle manager.
[amcl-6] [INFO] [1729844726.368108417] [amcl]: Destroying bond (amcl) to lifecycle manager.
[planner_server-3] Warning: class_loader.ClassLoader: SEVERE WARNING!!! Attempting to unload library while objects created by this loader exist in the heap! You should delete your objects before attempting to unload the library or destroying the ClassLoader. The library will NOT be unloaded.
[planner_server-3]          at line 127 in ./src/class_loader.cpp
[planner_server-3] terminate called without an active exception
[map_server-1] [INFO] [1729844726.413961558] [map_server]: Destroying
[amcl-6] [INFO] [1729844726.510903313] [amcl]: Destroying
[behavior_server-4] [INFO] [1729844726.617147852] [behavior_server]: Destroying
[bt_navigator-5] [INFO] [1729844726.691114069] [bt_navigator]: Completed Cleaning up
[bt_navigator-5] [INFO] [1729844726.691403004] [bt_navigator]: Destroying bond (bt_navigator) to lifecycle manager.
[INFO] [map_server-1]: process has finished cleanly [pid 5904]
[controller_server-2] [INFO] [1729844726.750655116] [controller_server]: Destroying bond (controller_server) to lifecycle manager.
[bt_navigator-5] [INFO] [1729844726.769778604] [bt_navigator]: Destroying
[controller_server-2] [INFO] [1729844726.786600085] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Destroying
[INFO] [amcl-6]: process has finished cleanly [pid 5914]
[controller_server-2] [INFO] [1729844726.868837134] [controller_server]: Destroying
[INFO] [behavior_server-4]: process has finished cleanly [pid 5910]
[INFO] [bt_navigator-5]: process has finished cleanly [pid 5912]
[INFO] [controller_server-2]: process has finished cleanly [pid 5906]
[ERROR] [planner_server-3]: process has died [pid 5908, exit code -6, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/nav2_planner/planner_server --ros-args --log-level info --ros-args -r __node:=planner_server --params-file /tmp/launch_params_un13augu -r /tf:=tf -r /tf_static:=tf_static'].
[lifecycle_manager-7] [ERROR] [1729844728.288065183] [lifecycle_manager_navigation]: Failed to change state for node: planner_server. Exception: planner_server/get_state service client: async_send_request failed.
[lifecycle_manager-7] [ERROR] [1729844728.288246243] [lifecycle_manager_navigation]: Failed to bring up all requested nodes. Aborting bringup.
[lifecycle_manager-7] [INFO] [1729844728.328804374] [lifecycle_manager_navigation]: Destroying lifecycle_manager_navigation
[INFO] [lifecycle_manager-7]: process has finished cleanly [pid 5916]


Welcome to Robotics, Illuminy. You said "I've tried creating a static_transform_publisher but it caused other problems then," but you don't give any information on what those problems were. The error you're getting is telling you explicitly that there's no transform between base_footprint and map. I'm assuming you created a static transform publisher to publish this information, but is that correct? What problems did this create?

Hello Chuck, I've edited the post and added the problems I've encountered when using static_transform_publisher. I simply get stuck in another wait which I do not know how to fix either. I do not know if the use of static_transform_publisher is correct for my problem, I saw it on some post on rosanswers saying it worked for them.

How did you try to create the static transform publisher?

Node(
package='tf2_ros',
executable='static_transform_publisher',
name='static_transform_publisher',
output='screen',
respawn=use_respawn,
respawn_delay=2.0,
parameters=[configured_params],
arguments=['0','0','0','0','0','0','1','map','odom'],
remappings=remappings)
ComposableNode(
package='tf2_ros',
plugin='tf2_ros::StaticTransformBroadcasterNode',
name='static_transform_publisher',
parameters=[configured_params],
remappings=remappings)
https://github.com/DVA490-474-Project-Course/robot-controller-interface/blob/main/config/launch/navigation_launch_ssl_robocup.py

I would check the transform from base_footprint to map:
ros2 run tf2_ros tf2_echo map base_footprint

You can also check the tf tree if it is not missing any transform:
ros2 run tf2_tools view_frames 

evince frames.pdf

If tf is ok. Then I would check the lifecycle of global_costmap
ros2 run lifecycle get /global_costmap/global_costmap

If it is not active, you should activate:
ros2 lifecycle set /global_costmap/global_costmap

In a summarize list the nodes and it's lifecycle status to check if some of them are missing (not launched) or inactive (sometimes this happen) and activate them.
Or check if some TF2 library or package is missing. Install everything related to TF2:
sudo apt-get install ros-humble-tf*

The * forces to install all derivative pkgs from tf...
Check your urdf models (sdf) if is correctly exported (if you are using Gazebo). It happened to me in some turtle it nav2 tutorials, these export were missing then the tf did not work, they are very important too.

Hello Marcus, thank you for your reply

checking the transform with echo provides the same message:

[INFO] [1729931174.574558133] [tf2_echo]: Waiting for transform map ->  base_footprint: Invalid frame ID "map" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist


The generated tree clearly shows map is lacking. Shouldn't AMCL provide this when i give map, map_topic and initial pose?
can not run lifecycle get

No executable found


The apt installed some packages but no difference in error

